# Send Custom Data using Bluetooth as Beacon in Flutter

Tags: flutter, ibeacon, beacon, altbeacon

I'm creating a PoC to send custom data using Bluetooth as Beacon in Flutter using the following [example](https://github.com/alann-maulana/flutter_beacon/tree/master/example) code. The library that I'm using is [flutter_beacon](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_beacon) and [beacon_broadcast](https://pub.dev/packages/beacon_broadcast) for scanning and broadcasting. I'm able to scan other Bluetooth's but when it comes to sending custom data String I'm unable to find a way. I've tried using different layout's found on internet, but as I'm unaware about it's meaning and how to configure it. I'm stuck here. **I want to send a String of about 12 chars**. Need help in creating layout or other means to send the data.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Bro did you find any proper solution regarding you usercase ? . As i have also the same usecase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AltBeacon with programmatic encoding of your characters inside the beacon’s three part identifier.

AltBeacon’s 3 part identifier has these parts:

ID1 (AKA Prox. UUID): 16 bytes
iD2 (AKA major): 2 bytes
ID3 (AKA minor): 2 bytes

You will need to allocate a few bytes as a matching indicator that it is “your” beacon so you do not misinterpret other AltBeacon transmissions your app sees.  If you need 12 characters, the 20 bytes above leaves you 8 to use for matching.  So you can use this scheme:

ID1: <8 matching bytes><first 8 chars of message>
iD2: <chars 9-10 of message>
iD3:

- For the 8 matching bytes, pick a unique byte pattern like 65 7a 5c 08 2d f4 c9 3a
- when transmitting construct your AltBeacon ID1, ID2, ID3 according to the scheme above
  *when scanning, use ranging with a *wildcard scan* with a beacon region with ID1 ID2 and ID 3 all set tip null.  This will give your app a callback every ~1 sec with all beacons detected regardless of identifiers
- compare the first 8 bytes of ID1 on any detected beacon to see if it is the same as your matching bytes.
- if you have a match, parse your 12 byte message out the end of ID1, ID2 and ID3